# Capture values >= 20 $ (without cents, currency symbol and spaces)

Tags: regex

I would like to capture $- (or £-)prices >= 20, without cents (pence), where the $ (£) may be in front of or after the value and the currency-symbol may be separated from the value by space(s) or not, e.g.:

```
$20
$3000
£ 60.67 (but only the '60'-part)
33$
500.99$ (but only the '500'-part)
90   £
```

Something like:

```
(?:[^\d][$£] ?)([\d]{3,}|[2-9][\d]{1})|([\d]{3,}|[2-9][\d]{1})(?: *.?[0-9]* ?[$£])
```

...which works, but simpler (or at least without the non-capturing `(?: )`-syntax because it doesn't work with my regex browser highlight extension.

I would like to use this to highlight prices e.g. on Amazon via a regex browser extension. If you happen to know a good one (which possibly even supports `(?: )`-syntax) I'd be happy to hear your suggestions, too :-)

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?<=[$£])\s*([2-9]\d|\d{3,})(?=[\.\s])|(?<!\.)([2-9]\d|\d{3,})(?=(?:\.\d+)?\s*[$£])
```

which splits the matching in two cases:

- case 1: your money symbol is found *before* the numeric value
- case 2: your money symbol is found *after* the numeric value

---

"**Case 1**": `(?<=[$£])\s*([2-9]\d|\d{3,})(?=[\.\s])`

- `(?<=[$£])`: the money symbol is followed by...
- `\s*`: spaces
- `([2-9]\d|\d{3,})`: 20 or bigger numeric values
- `(?=[\.\s])`: followed by either a dot (if decimal) or a space

"**Case 2**": `(?<!\.)([2-9]\d|\d{3,})(?=(?:\.\d+)?\s*[$£])`

- `(?<!\.)`: match is not preceeded by a dot
- `([2-9]\d|\d{3,})`: 20 or bigger numeric values
- `(?=(?:\.\d+)?\s*[$£])`: followed by optional dot and numbers (for decimal), mandatory spaces and the money symbol

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/HRsU75/1).

Comment: Thank you, this works both in my extension and in general! :-)

Comment: Is there no simple regex command that says something like "if a $-sign is contained anywhere in my regex match", something like a customized character class like e.g. `[$(MY_CUSTOMIZED_REGEX-EXPRESSION)]`?

Comment: No there's nothing like that. Also note that simpler regex patterns may match your expressions, although may be way more prone to mistakes (wrong matches) as well. This will avoid you validating wrong matches.